Transformation matrix for global displacements derivates to local ones
The derivatives of the displacements in the coordinate system $\bar{x} \bar{y} \bar{z}$ is given by
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \{\bar{L}\} & =
        \begin{Bmatrix}
            \bar{u},_{\bar{x}} &
            \bar{u},_{\bar{y}} &
            \bar{u},_{\bar{z}} &
            % 
            \bar{v},_{\bar{x}} &
            \bar{v},_{\bar{y}} &
            \bar{v},_{\bar{z}} &
            % 
            \bar{w},_{\bar{x}} &
            \bar{w},_{\bar{y}} &
            \bar{w},_{\bar{z}}
        \end{Bmatrix}^T
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
The derivatives of the displacements in the coordinate system $xyz$ is defined in a similar fashion way
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \{L\} & =
        \begin{Bmatrix}
            u,_{x} &
            u,_{y} &
            u,_{z} &
            % 
            v,_{x} &
            v,_{y} &
            v,_{z} &
            % 
            w,_{x} &
            w,_{y} &
            w,_{z}
        \end{Bmatrix}^T
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $\bar{u} = f(u, v, w)$, $\bar{v} = f(u, v, w)$, $\bar{w} = f(u, v, w)$, and $\bar{x} = f(x, y, z)$, $\bar{y} = f(x, y, z)$, $\bar{z} = f(x, y, z)$.
How to obtain the transformation between $\{\bar{L}\}$ and $\{L\}$, as defined by $[1]$?
\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \bar{u},_{\bar{x}} & \bar{u},_{\bar{y}} & \bar{u},_{\bar{z}} \\
        \bar{v},_{\bar{x}} & \bar{v},_{\bar{y}} & \bar{v},_{\bar{z}} \\
        \bar{w},_{\bar{x}} & \bar{v},_{\bar{y}} & \bar{w},_{\bar{z}}
    \end{bmatrix} =
    [\theta]^T
    \begin{bmatrix}
        u,_{x} & u,_{y} & u,_{z} \\
        v,_{x} & v,_{y} & v,_{z} \\
        w,_{x} & v,_{y} & w,_{z}
    \end{bmatrix}
    [\theta]
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
    [\theta] =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        \{v_1\} & \{v_2\} & \{v_3\}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
is the direction cosine matrix in the $\bar{x}$, $\bar{y}$, and $\bar{z}
$ directions.

I can obtain the transformation by using consecutively the Chain Rule, as follows:
Consider that
\begin{equation}
    \begin{Bmatrix}
        \bar{x} \\
        \bar{y} \\
        \bar{z}
    \end{Bmatrix} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        l_1 & m_1 & n_1 \\
        l_2 & m_2 & n_2 \\
        l_3 & m_3 & n_3
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{Bmatrix}
        x \\
        y \\
        z
    \end{Bmatrix} =
    [\Lambda]
    \begin{Bmatrix}
        x \\
        y \\
        z
    \end{Bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Using the chain rule method for $\bar{u},_{\bar{x}}$:
\begin{equation}
    \bar{u},_{\bar{x}} =
    \bar{u},_{x} x,_{\bar{x}} +
    \bar{u},_{y} y,_{\bar{x}} +
    \bar{u},_{z} z,_{\bar{x}}
    = \bar{u},_{x} l_1 +
    \bar{u},_{y} m_1 +
    \bar{u},_{z} n_1
\end{equation}
Performing the same procedure for other directions
\begin{equation}
    \begin{Bmatrix}
        \bar{u},_{\bar{x}} \\
        \bar{u},_{\bar{y}} \\
        \bar{u},_{\bar{z}}
    \end{Bmatrix} =
    [\Lambda]
    \begin{Bmatrix}
        \bar{u},_{x} \\
        \bar{u},_{y} \\
        \bar{u},_{z}
    \end{Bmatrix}
    \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation}
The same derivation performed in Eq. \eqref{1}  holds for $\bar{v}$ and $\bar{w}$, that is
\begin{equation}
    \begin{Bmatrix}
        \bar{v},_{\bar{x}} \\
        \bar{v},_{\bar{y}} \\
        \bar{v},_{\bar{z}}
    \end{Bmatrix} =
    [\Lambda]
    \begin{Bmatrix}
        \bar{v},_{x} \\
        \bar{v},_{y} \\
        \bar{v},_{z}
    \end{Bmatrix}
    , \qquad
    \begin{Bmatrix}
        \bar{w},_{\bar{x}} \\
        \bar{w},_{\bar{y}} \\
        \bar{w},_{\bar{z}}
    \end{Bmatrix} =
    [\Lambda]
    \begin{Bmatrix}
        \bar{w},_{x} \\
        \bar{w},_{y} \\
        \bar{w},_{z}
    \end{Bmatrix}
    \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation}
The derivatives in the right-hand side of Eq. \eqref{1} can be defined as
\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
        \bar{u},_{x} =
        u,_{x} \bar{u},_{u} +
        v,_{x} \bar{u},_{v} +
        w,_{x} \bar{u},_{w}
        =
        l_1 u,_{x} +
        m_1 v,_{x} +
        n_1 w,_{x}
        \\
        \bar{u},_{y} =
        u,_{y} \bar{u},_{u} +
        v,_{y} \bar{u},_{v} +
        w,_{y} \bar{u},_{w}
        =
        l_1 u,_{y} +
        m_1 v,_{y} +
        n_1 w,_{y}
        \\
        \bar{u},_{z} =
        u,_{z} \bar{u},_{u} +
        v,_{z} \bar{u},_{v} +
        w,_{z} \bar{u},_{w}
        =
        l_1 u,_{z} +
        m_1 v,_{z} +
        n_1 w,_{z}
    \end{gathered}
    \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation}
Equation \eqref{1} can be rewritten as
\begin{equation}
    \begin{Bmatrix}
        \bar{u},_x \\
        \bar{u},_y \\
        \bar{u},_z
    \end{Bmatrix}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        l_1 [I]_{3 \times 3} & m_1 [I]_{3 \times 3} & n_1 [I]_{3 \times 3}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \{L\}
    \tag{4}\label{4}
\end{equation}
where $[I]_{3 \times 3}$ is the identity matrix of dimension $3$. The same can be done for $\bar{v}$ and $\bar{w}$:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
        \begin{Bmatrix}
            \bar{v},_x \\
            \bar{v},_y \\
            \bar{v},_z
        \end{Bmatrix}
        =
        \begin{bmatrix}
            l_2 [I]_{3 \times 3} & m_2 [I]_{3 \times 3} & n_2 [I]_{3 \times 3}
        \end{bmatrix}
        \{L\} \\
        \begin{Bmatrix}
            \bar{w},_x \\
            \bar{w},_y \\
            \bar{w},_z
        \end{Bmatrix}
        =
        \begin{bmatrix}
            l_3 [I]_{3 \times 3} & m_3 [I]_{3 \times 3} & n_3 [I]_{3 \times 3}
        \end{bmatrix}
        \{L\}
    \end{gathered}
    \tag{5}\label{5}
\end{equation}
Combining Eqs. \eqref{1}, \eqref{2}, \eqref{4}, and \eqref{5}, it is possible to have a transformation between $\{\bar{L}\}$ and $\{L\}$:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{Bmatrix}
        \bar{u},_{\bar{x}} \\
        \bar{u},_{\bar{y}} \\
        \bar{u},_{\bar{z}} \\
        % 
        \bar{v},_{\bar{x}} \\
        \bar{v},_{\bar{y}} \\
        \bar{v},_{\bar{z}} \\
        % 
        \bar{w},_{\bar{x}} \\
        \bar{w},_{\bar{y}} \\
        \bar{w},_{\bar{z}}
    \end{Bmatrix} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        l_1 [\Lambda] & m_1 [\Lambda] & n_1 [\Lambda] \\
        l_2 [\Lambda] & m_2 [\Lambda] & n_2 [\Lambda] \\
        l_3 [\Lambda] & m_3 [\Lambda] & n_3 [\Lambda]
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{Bmatrix}
        u,_{x} \\
        u,_{y} \\
        u,_{z} \\
        % 
        v,_{x} \\
        v,_{y} \\
        v,_{z} \\
        % 
        w,_{x} \\
        w,_{y} \\
        w,_{z}
    \end{Bmatrix}
\end{equation}

$[1]$ O. C. Zienkiewicz and R. L. Taylor. The finite element method
for solid and structural mechanics. Elsevier, 2005.


What are the coordinate systems without and with a tilde?

Global and local, respectively. Both Cartesian coordinate systems.
